# SRM UI Addon Enhancement

Tags: sapui5

Could someone point to me what is wrong with my code. I have successfully added custom fields on the standard js file (SearchResult.view.js). I know that this is not the best practice on how to add custom fields. So I implemented a pre post method for adding custom fields.

Unfortunately when I moved my custom code block to the pre post method, instead of adding one 1 row (field) it adds multiple rows. I tried creating a counter but it doesn't work also

Below is my custom js code. Thanks in advance!

```js
function ADDCUSTOMFIELD1(){
 
};
 
ADDCUSTOMFIELD1.prototype.CUSTOM_POST_EXIT = function(methodName,view,controller, methodSignaure) {
 
if (!sap.ui.getCore().byId("ni_home"))
   return;
else add_custom_item();
};
 
 
function add_custom_item(){
if (sap.ui.getCore().byId("subMatrix")){
   // Supplier Name
   matrixSubRow = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow();
   control = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
     text : Appcc.getText("SUPPLIER_TEXT") + ":"
   });// control.addStyleClass("search_middle_spacing");
   matrixCell = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell();
   matrixCell.addContent(control);
   control = new sap.ui.commons.Label();
   control.bindProperty("text", "vendor_name");
   if (sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getRTL()) {
     control.addStyleClass("search_middle_spacingNewRTL");
     Appcc.addStyleClass(control, 'search_middle_spacingNew', true);
   } else
     control.addStyleClass("search_middle_spacingNew");
   matrixCell.addContent(control);
   // control = new sap.ui.commons.Label();
   // control.bindProperty("text", "itm_price");
   // control.addStyleClass("search_middle_spacing");
   // matrixCell.addContent(control);
   matrixSubRow.addCell(matrixCell);
   sap.ui.getCore().byId("subMatrix").addRow(matrixSubRow);
}
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your custom code block adds multiple rows because the `CUSTOM_POST_EXIT` function is called for every event on a view. Multiple events on a single view are fired (beforerender, render, ondatamodelloaded, etc). The methodName argument is the name of the event. Try this

```
function ADDCUSTOMFIELD1() {};

ADDCUSTOMFIELD1.prototype.CUSTOM_POST_EXIT = function(methodName, view, controller, methodSignaure) {
    var viewId = controller && controller.getView().getId();
    console.log(viewId, methodName)

    if (viewId === 'name_of_your_view' && methodName === 'onDataModelLoaded')
        //implement your customization
    }
}
```

You should see this function is being called for every view on your page an multiple times per view.

So you should check for which view and eventName the `CUSTOM_POST_EXIT` method is being called for and implement your customization only in 1 view/event combination.